# Any way to use (something comparable to) pytest with Java?

Tags: java, pytest

Relatively simple Java code projects. I would like to write tests with the simplicity of pytest for Java code -- just `test_foo()` top-level functions with `asserts`, and see helpful data when an assert fails.

What options should I look at? Any first-hand experience? Google suggested that jython + pytest might not be a well-supported combination.

Comment: JUnit is the defacto Java testing framework. To find other options, Google something like "Java unit testing"

Comment: [Junit](https://junit.org/junit5/)